# Update with ROW_NUMBER() OVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting error "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses." Can you please help me?

Iknow there are already some solutions to this problem but i don't know how to change it for my case. I am a beginner in SQL.

EDIT: I need to update column `[BREAG_GUEST_SEQ]` with correct sequence at UPDATE case. Every `[BREAG_BGL_ID]` have own sequence..

```
UPDATE G1
SET 
    G1.[BREAG_BGL_ID] = CASE WHEN G1.[BREAG_BGL_ID] <> G2.GROUP_ID THEN G2.GROUP_ID ELSE G1.[BREAG_BGL_ID] END
   ,G1.[BREAG_GUEST_SEQ] = CASE WHEN G1.[BREAG_BGL_ID] <> G2.GROUP_ID THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY G1.[BREAG_BRE_ID] DESC) + (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(BREAG_GUEST_SEQ), 0) FROM BOS_RESADDGUEST
                                                                                         WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, BREAG_DATEFROM) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) AND BREAG_BGL_ID = G2.GROUP_ID)
    ELSE G1.[BREAG_GUEST_SEQ] END
FROM 
    BOS_RESADDGUEST G1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
         [BRE_ID]
        ,MAX([BRE_DATEFROM]) AS DATEFROM
        ,MAX([BRE_DATETO]) AS DATETO
        ,MAX(BGL_ID) AS GROUP_ID
    FROM 
        BOS_RESERVATION
        LEFT JOIN BOS_UNIT_LIST ON BUL_ID = BRE_UNIT_ID
        LEFT JOIN BOS_UNITTYPE_LIST ON BUL_UNITTYPE_ID = BUT_ID
        LEFT JOIN BOS_GROUP_LIST ON BGL_ID = BUT_GROUP_ID
    WHERE
        BRE_ID = @DIALOG_BRE_ID
    GROUP BY [BRE_ID]
) AS G2
ON G2.[BRE_ID] = G1.[BREAG_BRE_ID]
```

Comment: The code looks like SQL Server, so I removed the MySQL tag.  Tag only with the database you are really using.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish would also help.  Your non-working query doesn't provide this information.  You should also qualify all column references so it is clear what tables the columns are coming from.

Comment: _I am a beginner in SQL_ No you are not. Without useful names or any understanding of your schema. it is difficult to suggest alternatives. The short answer is you cannot do what you desire. You must move the ROWNUMBER usage out of the update - perhaps into the (or another) derived table.

Comment: Side note, I suggest against such clauses as `DATEPART(YEAR, BREAG_DATEFROM) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())` in your `WHERE` (and `ON`). Use proper date boundaries so your query is SARGable.

Comment: Each unit (BREAG_BGL_ID) has its own sequence (BREAG_GUEST_SEQ). When changing a unit, the sequence for that unit can also be updated accordingly. Otherwise I don’t know how to explain.

Comment: You can only use window functions in the SELECT list and ORDER BY clauses of a query. Window functions precede ORDER BY. Drill processes window functions after the WHERE, GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses. You should create a derived table or a CTE , to be able to access the ROW_NUMBER()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isnt tested nor do you provide expected results or data structure. However, the issue is quite clear (as SMor has pointed out in the comments). This isnt the best code and the indentation is awful (i want it to be readable with scrolling left or right here on SO).

You most likely have to edit what Im joining on in the update statement at the end, because without further information from you i have to guess what the join predicate ought to be. Im sure you can figure it out from this point forward.

```
; WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT
            [BREAG_BRE_ID]
            , CASE 
                WHEN x.[BREAG_BGL_ID] <> x.GROUP_ID THEN x.GROUP_ID 
                ELSE x.[BREAG_BGL_ID] 
                END As NewBREAGBGLID
            , CASE 
                WHEN x.[BREAG_BGL_ID] <> x.GROUP_ID THEN ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER (ORDER BY x.[BREAG_BRE_ID] DESC) + 
                    (
                        SELECT ISNULL(MAX(BREAG_GUEST_SEQ), 0) 
                        FROM BOS_RESADDGUEST
                        WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, BREAG_DATEFROM) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) 
                        AND BREAG_BGL_ID = x.GROUP_ID
                    )
                ELSE x.[BREAG_GUEST_SEQ] 
                END AS NewBREAGGUESTSEQ
        FROM
            (
                SELECT g2.*, g1.[BREAG_BGL_ID], g1.[BREAG_BRE_ID], g1.[BREAG_GUEST_SEQ]
                FROM 
                    BOS_RESADDGUEST G1
                INNER JOIN 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            [BRE_ID]
                            ,MAX([BRE_DATEFROM]) AS DATEFROM
                            ,MAX([BRE_DATETO]) AS DATETO
                            ,MAX(BGL_ID) AS GROUP_ID
                        FROM 
                            BOS_RESERVATION
                            LEFT JOIN BOS_UNIT_LIST ON BUL_ID = BRE_UNIT_ID
                            LEFT JOIN BOS_UNITTYPE_LIST ON BUL_UNITTYPE_ID = BUT_ID
                            LEFT JOIN BOS_GROUP_LIST ON BGL_ID = BUT_GROUP_ID
                        WHERE
                            BRE_ID = @DIALOG_BRE_ID
                        GROUP BY [BRE_ID]
                    ) AS G2
                ON G2.[BRE_ID] = G1.[BREAG_BRE_ID]
            ) AS x
    )
UPDATE 
    [BREAG_BGL_ID] = c.NewBREAGBGLID
    , [BREAG_GUEST_SEQ] = c.NewBREAGGUESTSEQ    
FROM BOS_RESADDGUEST br
INNER JOIN cte c ON br.[BREAG_BRE_ID] =c.[BREAG_BRE_ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `ROW_NUMBER` into a derived table or CTE. You can update this directly, **no need to rejoin**.

You can also change the subquery to a windowed `MAX`

> Note also that date comparisons should not use functions against the column, as this can affect performance

```sql
UPDATE G1
SET 
    G1.[BREAG_BGL_ID] = CASE WHEN G1.[BREAG_BGL_ID] <> G2.GROUP_ID THEN G2.GROUP_ID ELSE G1.[BREAG_BGL_ID] END
   ,G1.[BREAG_GUEST_SEQ] = CASE WHEN G1.[BREAG_BGL_ID] <> G2.GROUP_ID THEN G1.rn + G1.MaxSeq ELSE G1.[BREAG_GUEST_SEQ] END
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY G1.[BREAG_BRE_ID] DESC) AS rn,
        ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN WHERE G1.BREAG_DATEFROM >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) THEN G1.BREAG_GUEST_SEQ END)
          OVER (PARTITION BY G1.BREAG_BGL_ID), 0) AS MaxSeq
    FROM
        BOS_RESADDGUEST G1
) AS G1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
         [BRE_ID]
        ,MAX([BRE_DATEFROM]) AS DATEFROM
        ,MAX([BRE_DATETO]) AS DATETO
        ,MAX(BGL_ID) AS GROUP_ID
    FROM 
        BOS_RESERVATION
        LEFT JOIN BOS_UNIT_LIST ON BUL_ID = BRE_UNIT_ID
        LEFT JOIN BOS_UNITTYPE_LIST ON BUL_UNITTYPE_ID = BUT_ID
        LEFT JOIN BOS_GROUP_LIST ON BGL_ID = BUT_GROUP_ID
    WHERE
        BRE_ID = @DIALOG_BRE_ID
    GROUP BY [BRE_ID]
) AS G2
ON G2.[BRE_ID] = G1.[BREAG_BRE_ID];
```